# How to print a statement with custom Ansible module?

Tags: python, ansible

I am implementing a new module for specific needs in my environment. I would like to print certain outputs (such as some `variables`) by this module, similar as `debug` module prints with `msg` parameter, but in a more customized way.

`AnsibleModule` class has `fail_json()` method which accepts `msg` argument to print on a failure, but I cannot find a way to print a message on success with `exit_json()`

I also don't know how builtin [debug module](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/utilities/logic/debug.py) works, found almost nothing except `DOCUMENTATION` and `EXAMPLES` in the module script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you want to be done on Ansible controller is done by action plugins (they are module's companions).

Take a look at some very simple plugin/module [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45082984/2795592).
You want to execute module, inspect it's result for your custom message, use `display.v` or `display.warning` or anything else to display this message and then return module's result back to Ansible core.

For this very reason [debug](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/690a626d0da92624235d6ef75f64c860b21b82ba/lib/ansible/plugins/action/debug.py) is an action plugin, and it's module only contains documentation, because all the work is done by plugin itself.